# How long does a material's magnetization take to align with an external field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Take a ferromagnetic material which has been exposed to an external magnetic field $h_0$ for a long time and therefore has and equilibrium magnetization $m_0$. The external magnetic field then flips to $h_1$, where $h_1=-h_0$. Over some period of time, the material's magnetization will reach equilibrium at $m_1$. How long does it take for the material's magnetization to reach this equilibrium?

I imagine the time required would be different for different materials and field strengths. Is there a material property that describes the time required for the material's magnetization to equilibrate or to reach some percentage of equilibrium? I am specifically interested in magnetite, but would be interested to see if there is data for other materials as well.

physicsguy19 asked a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/444011/how-fast-do-the-magnetic-domains-align-with-the-external-field), but I am interested in numeric values for the magnetization time for different materials.